# How to get the request body and response body in apache struts2? - post using $.ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am using ajax to call the webservice and struts to get the request parameters. This much is working fine, but I am trying to get the response in terms of json or I just need a success or failure flag in return from the server.
Here is my code..
Ajax part
index.jsp

```
function funcName(str, str1){
    $.ajax({
        url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webservicename",
        type : "post",
        data : {
            'key' : str,
            'Status' : str1
        },
        success : getResponse,
        error : function(xhr) {
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }

    });
}

function getResponse(xhr){
    $("#responseBody").html(xhr);
}
```

The service webservicename is mapped to an action in struts.xml to a java class named DataAction
DataAction.java

```
public class DataAction implements ServletRequestAware{
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = null;

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpServletRequest = arg0;
    }

    public String execute() {
        String key = httpServletRequest.getParameter("key");
        String status = httpServletRequest.getParameter("status");
        System.out.println(key +" "+ status);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Till here it is working, I modified the DataAction class and tried to write something to the response using Print writer but it is showing the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
```

The modified code

```
public class DataAction implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware{
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = null;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = null;


@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpServletRequest = arg0;
}



@Override
public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpServletResponse = arg0;
}

public String execute() {

    try {
            PrintWriter writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
            writer.println("hello server");
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String key = httpServletRequest.getParameter("key");
        String status = httpServletRequest.getParameter("status");
        System.out.println(key +" "+ status);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

How to get the response body and also the request body?

Comment: Use `stream` or `json` or some other result.

Comment: Tried json and it is working fine..

Comment: Answer your own question then and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you writing to the http servlet response, the response is already commited, so you can't use any dispatcher result such as `"success"`.

But you can return result `NONE` to prevent result execution after the action, and it's probably only the option.

Note, if you have any other interceptor on the stack, such as workflow interceptor, then it might return `INPUT` result, which is also a dispatcher result and should be excluded.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try this out, since it was an urgent for me, I tried json and it is working fine..