# Struts response raw string

Tags: java, struts2, struts, actionresult

I have a Struts project where I need to send a response as a raw string

`struts.xml`:

```xml
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
  <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"></constant>
  <constant name="struts.xwork.chaining.copyErrors" value="true"></constant>
  <constant name="struts.xwork.chainingcopyMessages" value="true"></constant>

  <package name="basicstruts6" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <default-action-ref name="init"></default-action-ref>


    <action name="init" class="some.class.path.mvc.ServiceTestAction" method="init">
      <result name="success">/WEB-INF/app/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="invokeService" class="some.class.path.mvc.ServiceTestAction" method="execute">
      <result name="success">/WEB-INF/app/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

  </package>
</struts>
```

In the `<action name="invokeService" class="some.class.path.mvc.ServiceTestAction" method="execute">` I want to repond with a raw string I define without using the `index.jsp` file as model.

I still want `some.class.path.mvc.ServiceTestAction` to handle the request, but want to write directly to the response writer

And at the same time I want to set the HTTP code of the response. In case it's an error I want to respond with HTTP 400 and write the body directly to the response writer.

Comment: What is the problem? Also why do you want to use a servlet stuff if you use Struts framework?

Comment: @RomanC I didn't develop the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to return index.jsp as a result then you should remove this code in the struts.xml

```
<result name="success">/WEB-INF/app/index.jsp</result>
    </
```

In the action class `execute()` method where the `return SUCCESS` put `return NONE`.

You can get `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` if your action class implements `ServletRequestAware` and `ServletResponseAware`.

You can also read this answer: [How to get the request body and response body in apache struts2? - post using $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44801033/573032).

In the action `execute()` method you write to the response some text using the servlet API. Something like

```
PrintWriter writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
writer.println("hello server");
writer.flush();
httpServletResponse.setStatus(400);
```